# How to disable UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a UIBarButtonItem that just doesn't want to get disabled. Short version: when I call

```
[myBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
```

Nothing happens.

`myBarButtonItem` is an IBOutlet in `myVIewController`. `myViewController` has been added as an object to `MainWindow` in Interface Builder. The `myBarButtonItem` outlet has been connected to the BarButtonItem, and has the corresponding `@syntesize` and `property` lines set.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *myBarButtonItem;
```

In myViewController.m,

```
@synthesize myBarButtonItem;
```

Anyone have an idea why the above `setEnabled` method has no affect? Thanks!

UPDATE: Fixed it! Don't know why, but apparently the outlet wasn't being set. I used my App Delegate as the parent object for the UIBarButtonItem, and all worked out.

Comment: Have you actually verified in the debugger that `myBarButtonItem` is not `nil`?

Comment: How have you declared the backing field in the @interface?

Comment: Why do you have @synthesize myBarButtonItem; in your header file 'myViewController.h'. Shouldn't that be in your implementation? I think once you move that it should fix it. I'm new to iOS development but whenever I have a property in the header file the corresponding synthesizer is in my .m (implementation) file.

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. It's in the implementation.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can disable the left navigation button from inside an UIViewController like this, without using any IBOutlet:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

To disable the right navigation button:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

**Swift3**

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 13):

If your toolbar has an IBOutlet (and you've checked to make sure it's non-nil), try:

```
[ [ [ myToolBar items ] objectAtIndex: myBarButtonItemIndex ] setEnabled:(NO) ];
```

Answer (score 4):

I used a different solution (Swift 4.2) for my rightBarButtonItems.

I had 3 buttons so used a for loop, then made an extension of UINavigationItem so I could use it throughout my app.

```
extension UINavigationItem {
func setRightBarButtonItems(isEnabled:Bool){
    for button in self.rightBarButtonItems ?? [UIBarButtonItem()] {
        button.isEnabled = isEnabled
    }
}
```

Then i can call it from my TableViewController

```
navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems(isEnabled: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Swift) I had 2 barButtonItems added as an array - so to disable them this did the trick

```
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.first?.enabled = false
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.last?.enabled = false
```