# Property "isEnabled" of UIBarButtonItem is an unrecognized selector in an extension of the class

Tags: swift, overriding, unrecognized-selector, class-extensions

In Swift 4 I want to use an **extension** of `UIBarButtonItem` that instantiates a special `UIBarButtonItem` object.
Here is my code (only the essential statements):

```
import Foundation

extension UIBarButtonItem {

    convenience init(staticImageName: String) {
        let staticView = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage(named: staticImageName))
        self.init(customView: staticView)
//      further code…
    }

    override open var isEnabled: Bool { 
        didSet { 
            print("didSet called") // Should be replaced by other code…
        } 
    } 

} // extension UIBarButtonItem
```

This extension builds without problems.

However when I run the app, I get a runtime error at the statement
`self.init(customView: staticView)`.
The log says:

```
-[UIBarButtonItem isEnabled]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe20c505180
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: isEnabled is not a property of UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: @Jacky But it is a property of its superclass `UIBarItem`

Comment: Please refer this, may be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784112/how-to-disable-uibarbuttonitem

Comment: Extensions are for adding new functionality. Extensions must not be used to override anything. Create a subclass if you want to override. From the Swift book: *"“Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.”*

Comment: Had similar issue. It seems UIBarButtonItem's `isEnabled` doesn't work as expected starting from Xcode 9 / iOS SDK 11. I changed UIBarButtonItem to use UIButton as a custom view to be able to use UIButton's `isEnabled`

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for clarification. The question then, however, is, why this is accepted by the compiler. Actually, my code was previously `override var isEnabled: Bool {...}`, and the compiler suggested `Overriding var must be as accessible as the declaration it overrides`and suggested as a fix to insert `open`.

Comment: I have no idea why the Swift compiler allows `override` in an extension since extensions are not supposed to be used to override anything. I'd call it a bug.

Comment: @rmaddy Anyway, this is the solution. Please post it as an answer, so that I can close the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions are not supposed to be used to override any existing functionality. Extensions are only supposed to be used to add new functionality.

For the Extensions chapter in the Swift book:

> “Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.”

So the proper solution is to subclass `UIBarButtonItem` if you wish to override existing functionality. Then use the subclass wherever you need it.